# Javascript (Chrome Extension): How to correctly execute multiple API calls using fetch and force code to wait for the calls to finish?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I am trying to create a chrome extension using the [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api). I am using an api call to get certain info, and then loop through the results and execute another api call per result. Once those calls finish, then the rest of the code will run. The issue that I am facing right now is that the rest of the code is executing before the fetches are returning the info.

Below is the function that is not working. I added 4 flags in the code to illustrate the problem better. The correct behavior should output flag 1, then loop 2, then loop 3, then 4. However, the actual behavior outputs flag 1 then loop 2 then 4, and then looping through flag 3.

One theory I have is that the cause is that I am using fetches inside of .then(). If this is the issue, how do I fix this? Or does it have anything to do with fetch being async? Any advice or helpful links would be super appreciated.

Thanks so much!

```
  let senderList = new Array();
  let init = {
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'json'
  };
  fetch(
    'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234',
    init)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log("Flag 1")
      let messageResponse = data.messages; //Array of Message Objects
      for (let i = 0; i < messageResponse.length; i++) {
        console.log("Flag 2")
        fetch(
          'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' + messageResponse[i].id +
              '?key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234',
          init)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(function(message) {
            let headers = message.payload.headers;
            console.log("Flag 3")
            for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
              if (headers[i].name == 'From'){
                senderList.push(headers[i].value);
              }              
            }               
          });          
      }
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Flag 4")
      onSuccess(senderList);
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async/await syntax with Promise.all that resolves when all promises are fulfilled:

```js
run();

async function run() {
  const list = await getSenderList();
  console.log(list, list.errors);
}

async function getSenderList() {
  const API_URL = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/';
  const API_KEY = '?key=...';
  const INIT = {method: 'GET', /* ... etc. */ };
  const data = await fetchJson(API_URL + API_KEY);
  const senderList = [];
  senderList.errors = {};
  await Promise.all(data.messages.map(async msg => {
    const msgData = await fetchJson(API_URL + msg.id + API_KEY, INIT);
    if (msgData instanceof Error) {
      senderList.errors[msg.id] = msgData;
      return;
    }
    const headers = msgData.payload.headers;
    for (const h of headers) {
      if (h.name === 'From') {
        senderList.push(h.value);
      }
    }
  }));
  return senderList;
}

function fetchJson(url, init) {
  return fetch(url, init).then(r => r.json()).catch(err => err);
}
```

Comment: That worked great for me! The behavior runs as expected now. Thank you so much!